# JavaScript Regex Question. How to split this string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to Regex and was wondering how to split this string `s4://test-dev/prefixes/file.mxf` into `['test-dev', 'prefixes/file.mxf']`. I want it to work for an unknown file path.

Ex)
`s4://test-dev/prefixes/file.mxf/newpath/anothernewpath` into
`['test-dev', 'prefixes/file.mxf/newpath/anothernewpath']`

Comment: `^[^\/]+\/\/([^\/]+)\/(.+)$`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting, use capture groups.

```js
url.match(/^[^/]+:\/\/([^/]+)\/?(.*)/).slice(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using regex for splitting (which is not necessary) you can use this regex: `s4:\/\/test-dev\/(.*)` and use first group (first parentheses) as second string (first one is always same as i can see), but easiest way is to find position of third '/' with this `var pos=str.split("/", i).join("/").length;` and then find substring from that position to end: `var res = str.substring(pos, str.length-pos);`

Answer (score 0):

`/^[\w+\:\/\/]+[-w+]/i`
matches 'text-dev'

`/w+\:\/\/[-w+]\/gi/`
matches the rest

Comment: The first regex matches your 'text-dev' or any text in that form coming after a protocol e.g text:// the second matches the rest of the text. Why not text it on the string first and see the output

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code below:

```js
let url = "s4://test-dev/prefixes/file.mxf/newpath/anothernewpath"
let match = url.match(/^s4:\/\/([\w-]+)\/(.+)$/)
let result = [match[1], match[2]]
console.log(result)
```

The result is:

```
[
  "test-dev",
  "prefixes/file.mxf/newpath/anothernewpath"
]
```